# UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(curUser, password) Is always false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

.net 6, Identity Core, using emails for usernames, MVC

The user is created in code with

```
var user = new DBModels.ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "Valid Email",
            Email = "Valid Email",
            Approved = true,
            LockoutEnabled = false,
            PhoneNumber = "(123) 456-7890",
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Doe",
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
            RenewalDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(50),
            ScreenName = "John.Doe",
            State = "AK",
            Avatar = "/assets/user.png"
        };
        var userResult = _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Password123!").Result;
        var roleResult = _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Default").Result;
```

I know the email/password pair I'm trying to compare is valid because I can login to the web app just fine.  I am trying to create an API controller for a mobile companion app and need to verify the email/password pair in the login method from the app. The API controller login method looks like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var curUser = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            if (curUser != null)
            {
                var verifyPassword = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(curUser, password);
                if (verifyPassword) .....
```

No matter what I do, when trying to verify a password, the check is always false. I find the correct user just fine but the password comparison is always false.  Any advice?

Answer (score -2):

So sorry ... this works perfectly fine when you enter the actually correct password in your test code!